# Adding second light hides the first on iOS unless quality is set to high

Tags: unity, lighting, ios

When I add a light in the scene then the light will show on the ground, but when I add a second light, neither of them show on the ground.

One light:

[image: One light's hot spot on a white ground plane]

Add second light:

[image: Ground plane with no hot spot]

My light is a spot light, and it's not working on the iOS device, but the PC is working fine.

I found this is related to quality settings: when I change to high, it shows both lights.

Is there a way to show two lights while using medium quality?

Comment: Did you set `Render Mode` of the second light to `Important`? And did you set [pixelLightCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-pixelLightCount.html) in `Project Setting -> Quality`?

Comment: @Mangata I think you could expand this into an answer showing the settings you'd recommend.

Comment: Depending on your target look for the game, there may be ways to achieve that look that will run faster / consume less battery than increasing the pixel light count. If you find your game is not running as well as you'd like with multiple lights, try posting a question showing your visual target and asking for an efficient way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renderer - pixelLightCount  , Medium is 1 and if you want more light show on the ground then set the number to more than one.